# Turn if else into a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I want to choose positions 1, 3, 7, 9.

I made an if else statement that solves the problem. Could this be implemented in a for loop.

```
  int move1 = (rand() % 4) + 1;
        if (move1 == 1)
        {
            move1 = 1;
        }
        else if (move1 == 2)
        {
            move1 = 3;
        }
        else if (move1 == 3)
        {
            move1 = 7;
        }
        else if (move1 == 4)
        {
            move1 = 9;
        }
```

Comment: `int moves[] = {1, 3, 7, 9}; move1 = moves[rand() % 4];

Comment: So you declare an Array 'moves' which elements are 1,3,7,9; and assign the random (1-4) array to move1. (sorry if my vocabulary is a bit off) brilliant none-the-less, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a loop, but usually you want to implement these kind of things with a switch statement. Something like this:

```
int move1;
switch(rand() % 4)
{
case 1:
    move1 = 1;
    break;
case 2:
    move1 = 3;
    break;
case 3:
    move1 = 7;
    break;
case 4:
    move1 = 9;
    break;

}
```